# getting a summary of every column of a df (dplyr::count)

Tags: r, dplyr, count

I have the following dataframe

```
tbl <- structure(list(col1 = c("a", NA, "b", NA, "c", "c"), col2 = c("n", 
"n", "b", "a", NA, "c"), col3 = c("z", "a", "z", "b", "1", "c"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 x 3
>   col1  col2  col3 
>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
> 1 a     n     z    
> 2 NA    n     a    
> 3 b     b     z    
> 4 NA    a     b    
> 5 c     NA    1    
> 6 c     c     c
> ```

Is it possible to apply the dplyr::count function to every column or some other function that returns the unique entries of every column and potentially the number each unique value appears?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can loop over the `names` with `map` and apply `count`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(names(tbl), ~ tbl %>% 
                     select(.x) %>% 
                     count(!! rlang::sym(.x)))
```

---

Or can apply `table` with `summarise_all` and return a `list` column

```
tbl %>%
    summarise_all( ~ list(table(.)))
```

Or for number of distinct elements

```
tbl %>%
    summarise_all(n_distinct)
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
lapply(tbl, function(x) as.data.frame(table(x)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! what does rlang::sym(.x) do?

Comment: @user171558 sorry, forgot to reply.  Here, the `names` are strings, and `sym` converts those strings to symbols which can be evaluated (`!!`) to return the value stored in that column

Answer (score 2):

One solution using `dplyr` and `purrr` could be, for the number of distinct values:

```
map(tbl, n_distinct)

$col1
[1] 4

$col2
[1] 5

$col3
[1] 5
```

For the counts:

```
map(tbl, table)

$col1

a b c 
1 1 2 

$col2

a b c n 
1 1 1 2 

$col3

1 a b c z 
1 1 1 1 2
```

Comment: Why map the first one. You could just  use `summarise()` instead.

Comment: @j3ypi because another user is using exactly that approach. I'm just adding one additional possibility :)